# 50 GB missing on 931GB harddrive

Tags: hard-drive

with df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       911G   11G  854G   2% /home
```

with lsblk

```
sda           8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   5,9G  0 part 
└─sda3        8:3    0 925,7G  0 part /home
```

im a bit confused, please help

Comment: Is it a fresh install ? If yes then reinstall ubuntu and pay attention while messing with partitions in installation process if any space is unallocated

Comment: Is this dual booted? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: explain the 50? and where is sda2?

Comment: `df -h` shows filesystem size while `lsblk` shows the size of the block device (partition). A partition and a filesystem are different things.

Answer (score 2):

When an ext4 filesystem is created, 5% of block is reserved by default. In your case, it accounts for `911*0.05=45.55`.

You can modify the percentage number to, say 1%, as follows:

`sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda3`

The reserved blocks are used for this (from [man tune2fs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs)):

> Set the percentage of the filesystem which may only be allocated by privileged processes. Reserving some number of filesystem blocks
> for use by privileged processes is done to avoid filesystem
> fragmentation, and to allow system daemons, such as syslogd(8), to
> continue to function correctly after non-privileged processes are
> prevented from writing to the filesystem. Normally, the default
> percentage of reserved blocks is 5%.

Comment: That reserved space is still visible when doing `df -h` and the like 

Comment: @matigo No, at least not in my case. Apparently `df -h` calculates the size as (Block Count - Reserved Blocks)*4096

Comment: What is the 5% reserved for?

Comment: @cocomac See `man tune2fs`, the `-m` flag.